# How to use Polymer template auto-binding in Polymer1.0?

Tags: css, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer doesn't provide much detailed documentation as now. So I am wondering how to use the template auto-binding feature. Previously with polymer 0.5

```
<template is=auto-binding>
```

would work. But doesnt work any more with Polymer 1.0.

My use-case is not building custom elements using Polymer instead build a web app using the existing iron, paper and gold elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new auto-binding templates are `<template is="dom-bind">`.  [There is documentation of it, though it is a little sparse at the moment](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-bind).